# Login call should hit before every call in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, api-testing

In my projects' auth token, I can use it once then it expires so obviously other calls are also failing. All the sub calls are configured in the csv file(s), tied with multiple jmx file integration not able to solve this one. Can anyone give me an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Beanshell Preprocessor allows you to run generic Java code and interact with JMeter environment, including updating variables.

See the following answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24513915

Note: I am on mobile - later I will update this answer to add more details.